# VBA - trendline equation only available when stepping through, not running

Tags: vba

I am trying to build a `collection` of the slopes from each trendline in an active chart. I can extract the trendline equations when stepping through the script using F8, but when I remove breakpoints and run with F5 `s.Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Text` only returns an empty string to `strEquations`. This is a very repeatable error where I can step through all series and extract all equations, or step through the first trendline and then run the rest and the script will break on the second trendline with `Run-time error 9. Subscript out of range` on the line `afterEquals = Split(upToX(0), " ")`.

Here is my script that runs on an active chart:

```
ThemeColor = 5 'msoThemeColorAccent enumeration starts at 5
Set trendEqns = New Collection
For Each s In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    'Debug.Print s.Name                         'debug print which series 's' is being manipulated
    s.Trendlines.Add                            'adds a trendline to series (s)
    s.Trendlines(1).Select
    s.Trendlines(1).DisplayEquation = True      'displays the equation for each new trendline
    s.Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = ThemeColor

    'THIS WORKS WHEN STEPPING THROUGH, but NOT RUNNING???
    strEquation = s.Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Text    'strEquation = "y = m*x + b"
    upToX = Split(strEquation, "x")                 'upToX = "y = m"
    afterEquals = Split(upToX(0), " ")              'afterEquals = "m"
    Slope = afterEquals(2)                          'Slope = "m"
    'Debug.Print Slope
    trendEqns.Add Slope
    ThemeColor = ThemeColor + 1
Next s
```

Comment: I hate this about VBA. There have been many times where I've had issues at runtime, but stepping through produced the expected results. Like Tim said, sometimes it needs to "catch up", I've even used sleep to wait x seconds between each loop of some functions to try and avoid this from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a loop with `DoEvents` to allow Excel to "catch up" with your code. In the loop you can check the value of the equation and exit when it's non-empty (of if some max time has passed so you don't end up stuck in the loop forever)

```
ThemeColor = 5 'msoThemeColorAccent enumeration starts at 5
Set trendEqns = New Collection
For Each s In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    'Debug.Print s.Name                         'debug print which series 's' is being manipulated
    s.Trendlines.Add                            'adds a trendline to series (s)
    s.Trendlines(1).Select
    s.Trendlines(1).DisplayEquation = True      'displays the equation for each new trendline
    s.Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = ThemeColor

    strEquation = ""
    t = Timer 'set timepoint
    Do
        DoEvents
        strEquation = s.Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Text    'strEquation = "y = m*x + b"
    Loop While strEquation = "" And (Timer - t) < 1
    
    upToX = Split(strEquation, "x")                 'upToX = "y = m"
    afterEquals = Split(upToX(0), " ")              'afterEquals = "m"
    Slope = afterEquals(2)                          'Slope = "m"
    Debug.Print Slope
    trendEqns.Add Slope
    ThemeColor = ThemeColor + 1
Next s
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I was guessing it needed time to catch up when running (instead of stepping) through and was trying to come up with a way to delay, but hadn't come up with something quite as clever yet. I also didn't want to delay for X seconds each time to prevent increasing runtime linearly based on the number of graphs/series, especially if my X seconds wasn't long enough and still broke occasionally. Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know, VBA is object-oriented programming and some objects are speficic redifinition of an other object which is call `Parent`to this object ( there is a hierarchic order). It's the case of trendline that is a "child" object from chart. As a result, in order to call trendlines properties, and to move back on the hierarchic steps, it's important to use the application `Parent` to let the code know that you want to activate trendline properties.On F8 mode, I think that the code understands that you want trendline's properties, but not on the F5 mode.

Try `nameofyourchart.Parent.Activate` it will works.